# sql*plus авторизация

Tags: oracle

username: login
service_name: service

Запускаю в Windows в командной строке:
sqlplus login@service , далее запрос пароля и сообщение "sp2-0306: Invalid option".

Если явно указать пароль, то работает, вот так: sqlplus login/password@service

Почему без явного указания пароля в строке не работает?

Comment: Пароль содержит спец. символы, пробелы, кавычки итд.? Измените пароль на более простой: pass123.

Comment: да, был символ @. С более простым паролем заработало. Спасибо

Comment: Или заключите пароль в кавычки, типа такого: `sqlplus login/"password"@service`. Должно помочь со многими спец. символами, но вот касательно именно символа `@` в пароле - нужно проверить. И кстати поведение может отличаться от версии к версии, в смысле, возможно что в старых версиях Oracle Client / SQL*Plus (вроде 11g / 12c) экранирование `@` в пароле не работало, а в последних версиях (вроде 19c / 21c) добавили.